# Loading images from phone to my app using Fresco library android / java

Tags: java, android, fresco

Hello I am new to Fresco and I am trying to load all the images in my phone to the app

when I use this URI:  `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20200206_222309.jpg`

with this code:

```java
ControllerListener listener = new BaseControllerListener();
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setUri(xuri)
        .setTapToRetryEnabled(true)
        .setControllerListener(listener)
        .build();
photosFragmentRecycler.setController(controller);
```

only the photo with the name `20200206_222309.jpg` is loaded 
how can I load all the images?
thanks in Advance

Comment: Easy, use `Glide` library instead.

Comment: is glide better than fresco ?  "in performance" @Aspicas

Comment: Sure. You can check `glide`and `picasso` libraries. They are so similar (with differents options)

Comment: It looks like the question is more about how to get the list of URIs instead of which library to use though. I've added an answer to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't depend on the image library used. You basically want to get a list of all camera images.
Something like this should get you the list of all URIs:

```
    fun getMediaStoreUris(context: Context): List<Uri> {
        val uris = mutableListOf<Uri>()
        context.contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID),
                null,
                null,
                null)?.use {
            val dataIndex = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
            while (it.moveToNext()) {
                uris.add(
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                it.getLong(dataIndex)))
            }
        }
        return uris
    }
```

Then, you can just create a simple RecyclerView adapter and ViewHolder and load images with Fresco:

```
  public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleViewHolder> {

    private List<Uri> mUris;

    SimpleAdapter(List<Uri> uris) {
      mUris = uris;
      setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View itemView =
          LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
              .inflate(R.layout.drawee_recycler_item, parent, false);
      return new SimpleViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.mSimpleDraweeView.setImageURI(mUris.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
      return mUris.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      return mUris.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    public void setData(List<Uri> uris) {
      mUris = uris;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }

  static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final SimpleDraweeView mSimpleDraweeView;

    SimpleViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      mSimpleDraweeView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.drawee_view);
    }
  }
```

and use the adapter:

```
    final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getMediaStoreUris(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Fresco has a full sample in their Showcase sample application here: https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/9fde53f963d07495118c61ea2d9a3fce575afeb7/samples/showcase/src/main/java/com/facebook/fresco/samples/showcase/drawee/DraweeRecyclerViewFragment.java

This is going to work if you allow permission to access local storage, there's a guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) or to test it, by simply going to "App Info" for your app and manually allowing it.

This is a very simple solution and in practice, you probably want to implement pagination etc. for the media store. But this should guide you in the right direction.